How does GPG Encryption/Decryption work on Spark?
I am doing GPG/PGP encryption/Decryption on spark. I have some large files. Sizes up to 30 GB . I am using a spark cluster with following configuration -

Worker Node - 16 GB , 4 Core . Min 2 , Max 8 Workers
Driver Node -  16 GB , 4 Core

MY Question is -> How does spark handle encryption decryption when the file is large and can not fit in single nodes memory ? Spark is Optimised for parallel processing , especially for tasks that can be divided in chunks , Whereas Encryption/Decryption tends to be sequential operation and cant be optimised with parallel process. So how does spark manage to decrypt a file larger than its memory ?

I looked into some online articles but did not get any good answer


By any chance are you using Azure databricks?

If you are using Databricks, you can try using bash to decrypt. Check this article https://medium.com/@anupamchand/pgp-encryption-using-python-in-azure-databricks-ef4bd56145ed. I faced the same issue for large files. But I didn't test for a 30GB file.

I have tested it in Azure data-bricks and it works fine. My question is - > how does it work ?  The large file would not fit it a single node -  and decryption process can not be parallelised -> but it works none the less. Hence I am interested to know the inner workings here
